# Replace a character except last x occurrences

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a file that has a bunch of hostnames correlated with IPs that looks like this:

```
x-cluster-front-1 192.168.1.2
x-cluster-front-2 192.158.1.10
y-cluster-back-1 10.1.11.99
y-cluster-back-2 10.1.157.38
int.test.example.com 59.2.86.3
super.awesome.machine 123.234.15.6
```

I want it to look like this:

```
x-cluster-front-1 192.168.1.2
x-cluster-front-2 192.158.1.10
y-cluster-back-1 10.1.11.99
y-cluster-back-2 10.1.157.38
int-test-example-com 59.2.86.3
super-awesome-machine 123.234.15.6
```

How can I replace the . (dots) from the first column with - (hyphen) in order to facilitate a sort by the second column? I was thinking of using sed to replace dots until the first space, or replacing every dot but the last three, but I'm having trouble understanding regex and sed. I can perform simple replaces but this is way over my head!

This is part of a larger script that I have been writing in bash. I am stuck at this part.

Answer (score 8):

**You can use AWK**

```
awk '{gsub(/-/,".",$1);print}' infile
```

**Explanation**

`awk` splits a line on whitespace by default. Thus, the first column of the line (`$1` in `awk`-ese) will be the one you want to perform the substitutions on. For this purpose, you can use:

```
 gsub(regex,replacement,string)
```

to perform the required substitution.

Note that `gsub` is supported only for `gawk` and `nawk` but on many modern distros `awk` is a softlink to `gawk`.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. I think an explanation would really benefit the asker and future readers as well.

Comment: @JosephR. Sorry I'm not good at explanation but I have tried and updated..

Comment: The POSIX spec for `awk` is based on `nawk`, so all modern `awk` implementations should have `gsub`. On Solaris, you may need `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk`.

Comment: @RahulPatil If you don't mind, I added a few lines that I think would help others.

Comment: @JosephR thanks.., it's seems perfect now.. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to do the substitutions on the first field, best is to use [Rahul's awk solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111322/22565) but beware it may affect the spacing (fields are rewritten with a single space in between them).

You can avoid it by writing it instead:

```
perl -pe 's|\S+|$&=~tr/./-/r|e' file
```

The `-p` flag means "read the input file line by line and print each line after applying the script given by `-e`". Then,  substitute (`s|pattern|replacement|`) the first sequence of non-space characters (`\S+`) with the matched pattern (`$&`) after substituting all `.` with `-`. The trick is to use `s|||e` where the `e` operator will evaluate an expression as a replacement. So, you can have one replacement (`tr/./-/`) applied to the match (`$&`) of the previous one (`s|||e`).

If you need to substitute every `.` with a `-` except the last 3 last ones, with GNU `sed` and assuming you have a `rev` command:

```
rev file | sed 's/\./-/4g' | rev
```

Comment: Note that the Perl solution assumes version 5.14 or higher (for the `/r` to work).

Answer (score 4):

Sed isn't the easiest tool for the job — see other answers for better tools — but it can be done.

To replace `.` by `-` only up to the first space, use `s` in a loop.

```
sed -e '
  : a                     # Label "a" for the branching command
  s/^\([^ .]*\)\./\1-/    # If there is a "." before the first space, replace it by "-"
  t a                     # If the s command matched, branch to a
'
```

(Note that some sed implementations do not support comments on the same line. GNU sed does.)

To instead perform the replacement up to the last space:

```
sed -e '
  : a                     # Label "a" for the branching command
  s/\.\(.* \)/-\1/        # If there is a "." before the last space, replace it by "-"
  t a                     # If the s command matched, branch to a
'
```

Another technique makes use of sed's hold space. Save the bit you don't want to modify into the hold space, do your work, then recall the hold space. Here, I split the line at the last space and replace dots by dashes in the first part.

```
sed -e '
  h           # Save the current line to the hold space
  s/.* / /    # Remove everything up to the last space
  x           # Swap the work space with the hold space
  s/[^ ]*$//  # Remove everything after the last space
  y/./-/      # Replace all "." by "-"
  G           # Append the content of the hold to the work space
  s/\n//      # Remove the newline introduced by G
'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bit easier to read than a large nasty regex.
Basically I just split the line into two fields at the whitespace and use sed on the first part.

```
while read -r host ip; do
    echo "$(sed 's/\./-/g' <<< "$host") $ip"
done < input_file
```

Depending on your shell you could also use ${host//./-} instead of the sed command.

Answer (score 2):

Since Rahul gave you [the canonical answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111322/26909) for your use case, I thought I'd take a stab at answering the titular problem: substituting all but the last x occurrences of a regex:

```
perl -pe '
    $count = tr{.}{.}; # Count '.' on the current line
    $x = 3;
    next LINE if $count <= $x;
    while(s{\.}{-}){   # Substitute one '.' with a '-'
        last if ++$i == $count - $x # Quit the loop before the last x substitutions
    }
$i = 0
' your_file
```

The above code (tested) does not assume that you have space-separated fields. It will replace all dots on a line with dashes except the last 3 dots. Replace the `3` in the code to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use many different tools for this. Rahul Patil already gave you a `gawk` one so here are a few others:

- perl

  ```
  perl -lane  '$F[0]=~s/\./-/g; print "@F"' file
  ```

  The `-a` switch causes perl to automatically split input lines on whitespace and save the resulting fields into the array `@F`. The first field, therefore, will be `$F[0]` so we replace (`s///`) all occurrences of `.` with `-` in the first field and then print the entire array.
- shell

  ```
   while read -r a b; do printf "%s %s\n" "${a//./-}" "$b"; done < file
  ```

  Here, the while loop reads the file and automatically splits on whitespace.This creates two fields, `$first` and `$rest`. The construct `${first//pattern/replacement}` replaces all occurrences of `pattern` with `replacement`.

Comment: +1 While `perlrun(1)` will tell you that `-a` is "autosplit mode", I prefer to think of it as "`awk` mode" :D

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\./-/' <file name>
```

Without using `g` at the end of the command you can do this… This will simply replace the 1st occurance of the pattern